# TypeScript is unable to infer type properly from a typed string variable

Tags: typescript

I am trying to use a "freely" created `string` as a key for an object.

```
interface CatState {
    name: string,
    selected: boolean,
    color: string,
    height: number
}

interface DogState{
    name: string,
    selected: boolean,
    race: string,
    age: number,
    eyeColor: string
}

export interface Animals {
    animals: {
        cat: {
            cats: CatState[],
            allSelected: boolean,
        },
        dog: {
            dogs: DogState[],
            allSelected: boolean,
        },
    }
};

const selectAnimal = (allAnimals: Animals, animal: keyof Animals['animals'], index:number) => {
    const animalPlural = `${animal}s` as keyof Animals['animals'][typeof animal]
    allAnimals.animals[animal][animalPlural][index].selected= true
}
```

This highlights `.selected` with the message

> Property 'selected' does not exist on type 'boolean'.

Here is a [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMJzAZTBlBvAKGWORDgFsIAuZAZzClAHMAaIk2iAGwgUgBMaAIwD2InnBBsSyBOJFQa9RiFbtiACwjAmGsDRABXckOgEAvgQKhIsRCgAiIptlyEZZSkobNpHbrwCwmISUurIUPbeKmoycEzUpMamUH7EEACeEKjyinQ+qhZWEAAeAA4KYMg20PBIyACCIMDkcFy0yO4kki1ttDRdMsQIGAPhQyQjYP1oGK6QANoAumkT3VxcmAF8EILIouIQkqsy5ick-M5ja0OXTDNOLjiLK+NrbZvbQfshR2E3Z3ClnMAG4rHIQPQ6F8GhtkABeZAACg+TV67RoaNa7RYyB62JoAGtMiIYI1mtjaAsAOT4vrUpYASgRAD5OuEIVC6VwAApcQyRLgI5AAAwAJHhueZaCK8R1iRlSeT0VTaRT6UsFmAMmUIEruUtwqj1e0AHTcqkGhbcvkCtpLU2cHg7fjChiGCAWIA). Is there a workaround for this, or is this simply not possible?

Comment: What is the type of the parameter `state` and why is the `action` parameter type specified and not `state`?

Comment: Is this some type of reducer? If state is of type `FooState` then where does the `items` property come from?

Comment: There's a lot of things to note here. 1. As you've written the code there is **no point** to having CatState and DogState: Typescript is structurally typed not nominally typed so those two interfaces are identical. 2. You are making a lot of assertions to the compiler without verifying that the values are what you think they are, so be careful 3. You've got deep nested property accesses on a single line which makes it very hard to figure out where the problem is. Assign all the intermediate steps to variables to assist in debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for this to work you need to make `selectAnimal` [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html).

You might think it should be able to deal with an `animal` input of a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types), but the compiler isn't able to properly type check a single block of code that uses multiple expressions that depend on the same union type.  It loses track of the *correlation* between `` `${animal}s` `` and `allAnimals.animals[animal]`.  The formers is of type `"cats" | "dogs"` and the latter is of a type like `{cats: CatState[]} | {dogs: DogState[]}`, and you can't generally index into the latter with the former, because "what if you've got `{cats: CatState[]}` and you're indexing with `"dogs"`?"  That can't happen, but the compiler is unable to see it.  TypeScript can't directly deal with correlated unions this way.  That's the subject of [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).

If you want a single code block to work for multiple cases, the types need to be refactored to use generics instead, as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).  Here's how it might look for your example:

```
interface AnimalStateMap {
    cat: CatState,
    dog: DogState
}

type AnimalData<K extends keyof AnimalStateMap> =
    { [P in `${K}s`]: AnimalStateMap[K][] & { allSelected: boolean } }

export interface Animals {
    animals: { [K in keyof AnimalStateMap]: AnimalData<K> };
};
    

const selectAnimal = <K extends keyof AnimalStateMap>(
    allAnimals: Animals, animal: K, index: number) => {
    const animalPlural = `${animal}s` as const;
    // const animalPlural: `${K}s`
    const animalData: AnimalData<K> = allAnimals.animals[animal]
    animalData[animalPlural][index].selected = true;
}
```

The `AnimalStateMap` is a basic key-value type representing the underlying relationship in your data structure.  Then `AnimalData<K>` is a mapped type that encodes as a [template literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) the concatenation of `s` onto the type of the keys (giving such plurals as `gooses` and `fishs` ‍♂️) and that the value type is of the expected animal array.  And that there's an `allSelected` property.

Then your `Animals` type explicitly written as a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over `keyof AnimalStateMap`, which will help the compiler see the correlation when we [index into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) it.

Finally, `selectAnimal` is generic in `K extends keyof AnimalStateMap` and the body type checks because `animalPlural` is of just the right generic type `` `${K}s` `` which is known to be a key of `animalData`, which is `AnimalData<K>`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMJzAZTBlBvAKGWORDgFsIAuZAZzClAHMAaIk2iAGwgUgBMaAIwD2InnBBsSyBOJFQa9RiFbtiACwjAmGsDRABXckOgEAvgQKhIsRCgAiIptlzJCMspSUNm0jty8AsJiElLqyFD2PipqMnBM1KTGplD+xBAAnhCo8op0vqoWVjbQ8EjIAIIgwORwXK6QALJwAA7uEQgYNOhYOJDpyPzONE4u-RDFBGCZrSjVtfUOGHAAPADSyBAAHpAg-LTIANZZIjBVNXUNEy2tAHzIALwReMgA2gAKyKDIAAYAJHh1uZaL8ALo0BZXRoQW5vdZgt5g5DmZAAMncyHqDUCfAggmQonEEEkKKsO1aCjA33AZXsF0WXEOHhIkkZtBor3hNOOp3OUPqMNuEIZV2WOA2D3MAG4LLKCHIQPQ6LiwJUuFwnsgNltdhB9ocTpkzqLBTc2ncABTYgVMyGXeq0FhYh1cGjrACUTweLOIiuVbKuHy4hiimsef0BgfqIN+WMO-rAspkAHoU7IRErqdGuMHQ-UaACgbHOpmA67xXB7YzK5KtTbXbQAHQ52hvHNgiI5ystjWYVX4rUMQwQZOsisrduuvNhsFNmAKACiiA0lu23uQ2ybnB4eP4Q6gI49svMQA)

Answer (score 1):

You should use a similar variable name (e.g. `states`) inside `FooState.animals[type]` instead of `cats` and `dogs`. Without doing so, TypeScript sees `cats` and `dogs` as two unrelated objects.

See [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FASwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZQAQEEwgLYIDYDKEC0qA3sKlamAtlAFyoDOEM4A5gNyXXNR4oSaABMmAIwD2kwQjA8AvsFCRYiFKgDCJIiTRQAHtDAjmGLLkLFSFaqiQzJMJq3ZhuvKgAsoIDl4gmMABXbHFYRWVwaHhkNAARSQ5dUkNjU3McfBS0W2oHPCcXNk4eOx8-AKDQ8JhI4EMABycIVGi1ONQAMWkczCy8AFFIGABPAB4c1DSoEzN+yxyAPnJPFmsoZiYcgG0AXTLqbCdGVElxACshCEOqfEIBa6gxVCkZKDl6ppa21ViNHqSKZ5O4WfBbVZ2OxIEgAfiYgL6YKGIwm2ggy1uUJESXh3V6GwW+GGbAmiWSGyWWKUCh4DQMzRgrQgo0aaCJeAAKqy0ABeVAAaygo0kcHxQI2OwA5HIBswpQdlN8mag4MEwMIQJIwCxHsIAPIweKbPUQDkAClYegRBL0ABpUMgIFqwEwyKhGghRoUEC93eARIZqmFYA6WWymBzuWzUApYwBKSH5bWscgBwxhnkKN2-QMGYO1TMRzKWaNoOP8p0ugB0nu9kl9WIcYFTssWG1Q-Kt0GrbfBO3DUD2AEJq93Njt0wY9o75sicli+1Y9GPTc9O6hh0ucqvBMJnsAFEA) TypeScript playground. Note that I've the removed `PayloadAction` type since the OP did not provide it and added a type to the object destructuring.

`FooState` can also be converted from a regular type to an interface. Also notice I've add a `FooStateAnimalEntry` interface. Adding this interface gives you more organized code and improves readability.

You will probably want to change the type of `FooStateAnimalEntry.more`, which may need to be done with [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html).